# Moth in canned peas!

Tags: consumer-protection

I bought a bottle of peas in a supermarket in Germany. When I went home, I found a moth that had been soaked for a long time. How should I protect my legal rights?I have the receipt. A lot of thanks!

Comment: Aside from returning it to the store where you bought it for a refund or replacement, are there other rights you're referring to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first course of action should probably be to return to the store, explained what happened, and ask either for another jar of peas or for your money back.  Bring your receipt and the jar of peas with the moth in it.

If the store refuses to refund your money or replace the jar of peas, you might try approaching the manufacturer.  In my experience, European packaged foods have a telephone number for customer service among the fine print on the back of the label.

If the manufacturer is no help, you could consider taking legal action, but the costs of doing so would be far greater than any benefit you are likely to realize.  That is the same reason why the store and the manufacturer will probably handle your claim without much resistance; the cost of resisting is far higher than the cost of a jar of peas.